# Can I format the arguments in a table and provide the rows to a shell block as arguments?

Tags: org-mode, shell

In `org-mode`, is possible to provide arguments formatted as a table to a shell block?

E.g.

### argument

```
|a|b|
|c|d|
```

### shell script

```
echo $a
```

### expected results

```
a b
c d
```

Basically, I want `org-mode` to read the values in the table row by row and provide them to the shell block as *space* separated strings.

Comment: What do you want to do with that input afterwards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#+NAME: foo
| a | b | one |
| c | d | two |

#+BEGIN_SRC bash :var tbl=foo
for key in "${!tbl[@]}"; do
  row=${tbl[$key]}
  echo $key $row
done
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
| c | d | two |
| a | b | one |
```

Note that row order is not preserved.

If you want to break out the columns, you can do that with `read`:

```
#+BEGIN_SRC bash :var tbl=foo
for key in "${!tbl[@]}"; do
  row=${tbl[$key]}
  IFS=" " read c0 c1 <<< ${row[@]}
  echo $key $c1
done
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
| c | two |
| a | one |
```

Comment: You are using associative arrays (the index is a hash of the key):  like almost all associative arrays, order of the rows is not preserved. You could use indexed arrays instead.

Comment: How could I use indexed arrays? `C-v C-v C-v` expansion `(org-babel-expand-src-block)` expands to `unset tbl; declare -A tbl; ...` where according to bash `-A` makes the array associative, not indexed.

Comment: Yes, bash (and how babel does things with it) seems hopeless, so forget bash and write it in lisp or python. The OP can compose a couple of source blocks to do whatever  he wants (which the question  does not make clear at all).

Comment: Luckily, the order does not matter in this case. But I certainly would like to learn if there's a way to preserve the order. Thanks!

Comment: I'd submit a patch for ob-shell.el changing "-A" to "-a". I don't think this would have any negative side effects.